# problem with nextgen plugin

Tags: plugins, gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I have a problem with Nextgen gallery,after activating some plugins it doesn't show the submit buttons(insert, cancel).

Then i have deactivated all plugins, but that doesn't help.

I haven't any experience with wordpress, so any suggestions would be very useful.

Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

one of those weird problems.

try deactivating - reactivating nextgen - otherwise, u might have to delete it and re-install it
make sure to backup ur media

good luck

Comment: when i try to re-install it, it suggest to make the backup  for the database, and for the files too. Why i have to backup my images? Is it possible then i'll lose the files after re-installing the plugin? (i have about 300Gb files, so it'll we hard work to backup them all)

Comment: backing up should be easy - you can copy the files on the same hosting from ur cpanel or you can wget it to another source - you don't have to download your content, just copy on hosting under another folder name and outside of ur wordpress if possible